# Unable to save content language configuration

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, configuration

My Drupal 8 website is multilingual and has many entity type bundles for nodes, taxonomy terms, paragraphs, media et cetera. This leads to a content language settings form (admin/config/regional/content-language) with more than thousand translatable-checkboxes.

Currently I'm not able to save this form. In the first place the form seemed to be successful submitted but changes have not been saved. This was caused by insufficient php setting value for `max_input_vars`, which could be solved by setting it to `6000`. Now I'm struggling with a timeout. After submitting the form the request fails after some minutes.

Here are the php settings of my Drupal VM:

```
php_version: "5.6"
php_memory_limit: "1024M"
php_realpath_cache_size: "1024K"
php_opcache_enabled_in_ini: true
php_opcache_memory_consumption: "192"
php_opcache_max_accelerated_files: 4096
php_max_input_vars: "6000"
php_max_execution_time: "720"
php_post_max_size: '64M'
```

How can I get around this issue? Which resource bottleneck could cause this?

Comment: How many input fields do you have on that page? With `document.querySelectorAll('input').length` on the Dev-Tools you will get an info about that. I have a multilingual site too with about 40 bundles. But I have more fields on the permissions settings page. On the content language configuration page I have only 454 input fields, on the permissions settings page there are 2316 input fields. The only change I made was to increase the `max_input_vars` to 2500.

Comment: @RWAM: Currently there are 148 bundles listed with 1622 checkboxes. It's I quite complex website. The permission settings page is also very large but you can decrease the number of input fields by setting permissions on each role separately.

Comment: What's your value for the php setting `max_input_time`? Otherwise you can test to increase other settings. In my environment I use the following values: `realpath_cache_size: 4096K`, `post_max_size: 128M`, `opcache.max_accelerated_files: 10000`.

Comment: How can you get around this issue? If you are desperate, you could hack core and remove array keys from `$entity_types` in the first line of buildForm() in core/modules/language/src/Form/ContentLanguageSettingsForm.php.

Comment: @RWAM: `max_input_time` is set to `60`. I will test your suggested values and report back.

Comment: @4k4: No, I'm not that desperate – at least not yet.

Comment: Then you could file an issue to make this possible in UI, selecting the entity types before the form is displayed.

Comment: @RWAM: None of your suggested values made any noticeable difference.

Comment: I could finally save the form without a timeout by updating PHP on my VM to 7.1. But it still does take a very long time.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the max_input_vars fix and that didnt work (i have alot of custom entities on the page and was hoping this would work).
I had to check the entity, pretend it was called MyCustomEntity in 'Custom language settings' at the top... but also scroll down to the individual MyCustomEntity settings further down on the page, and also check that checkbox. When I saved, now it worked

Answer (score 0):

Today I had to struggle again with this problem and could solve it by disabling Xdebug. So to sum up this could help:

- increase `memory_limit` and `max_execution_time`
- update to latest PHP version (at least 7.1)
- make sure Xdebug is not enabled when saving the settings form (e.g. via browser extension or general xdebug settings on server/vm)